# MvvmCross CloseTo ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

In MvvmCross is there a way to ask the navigation service to close to a specific viewModel?

For example let's say I have 3 view models

`A B C`

I have navigated from A to B to C.

`A -> B -> C`

In the C view I press a Done button and would like to go back to view A.

Is there a way to do something like this in the C viewModel?

`_navigationService.Close<A>(this);`

Comment: The `IMvxNavigationService Close` would close the specific viewmodel. Please check the link below. https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/3063

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Are you suggesting I simply call close for all the viewModels I wish to close in ViewModel C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are on `Xamarin.Forms` (if not let me know and I'll update the answer because it's not that simple), in the `IMvxNavigationService` you have the `ChangePresentation(...)` method which uses a hint object to tell the framework what you want to do.

```cs
 Task<bool> ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

[Here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/20cde944db7acba7d7b4b8bccf86639e89cf7e55/MvvmCross/Presenters/Hints) you have the different out-of-the-box hints that the framework provides.

To address your issue you can just use `MvxPopPresentationHint`:

```cs
_navigationService.ChangePresentation(new MvxPopPresentationHint(typeof(A)));
```

or if `A` is your root ViewModel, you can just use `MvxPopToRootPresentationHint`:

```cs
_navigationService.ChangePresentation(new MvxPopToRootPresentationHint());
```

HIH

Comment: I am not using forms. I’m using Android and iOS.

Comment: It looks like you have to subclass the platform view presenters for iOS/Android if you wish to do this. I am marking this answer as correct as there isn't really a solution for the time being. https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/4032

Comment: yes, you have to subclass the view presenter on the platform and send a custom Hint. Which then depending on the hint you implement the closing on each platform.I'm sorry I didn't answer sooner. If you have any problems with that let me know and I'll complete the answer as soon as I can